# Passing RecyclerView CardView Clicked Item Data To Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a question about passing clicked cardview data to activity, and here the full story :

1. I have an Activity called "Details", which contains 2 TextViews in it's layout, Title & Description .
2. I have setup a fragment ( tab_1 ) which contain the recyclerview codes and the the items data, each item of those contain : title & description .

What i want :

When the user click the item, it will open the Details Activity, and change Details layout title, with clicked item title, and the same for description .

I've manged to create the other activity as an example, and made intent to start it, plus adding "addOnTouchlistener" thanks to Stackoverflow, i've found the way to make it .

So, how to make this alive? I've tried many ways of the available answers on Stackoverflow, but all of them not working, or not related to my request .

Here are my files :

itemsdata.java :

```
public class itemsdata {
int CatPic;
String title;
String Descr;
int Exapnd;
int expand_no;
```

tab_1.java ( fragment )

```
public class tab_1 extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
public RecyclingViewAdapter adapter;
private Activity context;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)layout.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener
            (getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }
            }));
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    adapter = new RecyclingViewAdapter(getActivity(),Listed());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return layout;

}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    final List<itemsdata> filteredModelList = filter(Listed(), query);
    adapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return true;
}

private List<itemsdata> filter(List<itemsdata> models, String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();

    final List<itemsdata> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (itemsdata model : models) {
        final String text = model.title.toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}

public List<itemsdata> Listed()
{
    //Titles Strings
    String sys_title1 = getString(R.string.system_item_title_1);
    String sys_title2 = getString(R.string.system_item_title_2);
    String sys_title3 = getString(R.string.system_item_title_3);

    //Description Strings
    String sys_descr1 = getString(R.string.system_item_desc_1);
    String sys_descr2 = getString(R.string.system_item_desc_2);
    String sys_descr3 = getString(R.string.system_item_desc_3);

    //Adding New Cards
    List<itemsdata> data = new ArrayList<>();

    //Categories Icons New Items ** Make It The Same
    int[] icons = {
            R.drawable.facebook_icon ,
            R.drawable.twitter_icon ,
            R.drawable.twitter_icon
    };

    //Expand Button New Items
    int[] expandbutton = {
            R.drawable.expanded ,
            R.drawable.expanded ,
            R.drawable.expanded
    };

    //UnExpand Button New Items
    int[] unexpandbutton = {
            R.drawable.ca_expand ,
            R.drawable.ca_expand ,
            R.drawable.ca_expand
    };

    //Titles New Items
    String[] titles = {
            sys_title1 ,
            sys_title2 ,
            sys_title3
    };

    //Description New Items
    String[] Description = {
            sys_descr1 ,
            sys_descr2 ,
            sys_descr3
    };


    for(int i = 0;i<titles.length && i < icons.length  && i < Description.length && i < unexpandbutton.length && i < expandbutton.length  ; i++)
    {
        itemsdata current = new itemsdata();
        current.CatPic = icons[i];
        current.title = titles[i];
        current.Descr = Description[i];
        current.expand_no = unexpandbutton[i];
        current.Exapnd = expandbutton[i];
        data.add(current);
    }
    return data;
}

}
```

Details Activity :

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

TextView title;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details);
    title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.details_title);
}
```

EDIT : I've made it, i have added a button which open the fragment, and passed the data, in the Adapter, but i want it via tab_1.java, not the Adapter, i mean i want to click on the item to open the fragment, not on a button, here a snap from my Adapter code ( i've added it in OnBindViewHolder )

I've setup a OnClick and implemented the Vew.setOnClick ..etc, but when i click the item, nothing happen.

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyRecycleViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),DetailsActivity.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //Referencing Data
    final itemsdata currentobject = mdata.get(position);
    //Referencing Items
    holder.ProbTitle.setText(currentobject.title);
    holder.ProbDescr.setText(currentobject.Descr);
    holder.CategoryPic.setImageResource(currentobject.CatPic);
    holder.ExpandButton.setImageResource(currentobject.Exapnd);
    holder.ExpandNoButton.setImageResource(currentobject.expand_no);
        //What Happen When You Click Expand Button .
    holder.ExpandButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("TitleKey",holder.ProbTitle.getText().toString());
            v.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    );

public static class MyRecycleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{



    SwipeLayout swipeLayout;
    //Defining Items .
    TextView ProbTitle;
    ImageButton ExpandButton;
    TextView ProbDescr;
    ImageButton ExpandNoButton;
    ImageView CategoryPic;
    /*
    TextView Card_Star;
    TextView Card_UnStar;
    */
    TextView Card_Share;

    //Referencing Resources
    public MyRecycleViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ProbTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prob_title);
        CategoryPic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_pic);
        ProbDescr = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prob_descr);
        ExpandButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.expand_button);
        ExpandNoButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.expand_no_button);
        /*
        Card_Star = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_star);
        Card_UnStar = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_unstar);
        */
        Card_Share = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_share);
        swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipe);

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create an `Interface` inside your adapter containing `methods`. And while implementing your Adapter, those methods will be implemented in your activity and you can perform whatever action you want.

```
    public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecycleViewHolder> {

    public interface Callbacks {
        public void onButtonClicked(String titleKey);
    }

    private Callbacks mCallbacks;

    public Adapter() {

    }

    @Override
    public MyRecycleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_details, null);
        return new MyRecycleViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyRecycleViewHolder holder, final int i) {

        holder.ExpandButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mCallbacks != null) {
                    mCallbacks.onButtonClicked(holder.ProbTitle.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return;
    }

    public void setCallbacks(Callbacks callbacks) {
        this.mCallbacks = callbacks;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try do this on your onItemClick()

`Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("title", yourTitle);
 i.putExtra("description", yourDescription);
 view.getContext().startActivity(i);`

and when oncreate in your DetailActivity,do this

`String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
 String description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");`

so you can pass title and description to DetailActivity

Comment: Please check the edit, your way won't work, the problem in getting that string, only possible way is from the Adapter, but from the tab_1.java, it's not possible .

Comment: @AboHani RecyclerView doesn't provide onItemClickListener and onItemLongClickListener,you should set it in adapter only...or you can create a interface in adapter like this `public interface OnItemClickLitener
    {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
        void onItemLongClick(View view , int position);
    }
`and call it when each item clicked or long clicked,so you can set a listener in tab_1.java now.

Comment: Yeah, I've added at first in this way, but i wasn't able to pass the data, anyway i've made it via referencing cardview in the adapter and passing the data using intent.putExtras .
btw, if you have knowledge in searchview please check my question in my profile, and thanks for your answer :) .

Comment: @AboHani every class that extend from View can set an `onClickListener()`,so just set this listener to your item's root view,no need to add a new button. and change this line`i.putExtra("TitleKey",holder.ProbTitle.getText().toString());
`to`i.putExtra("TitleKey",currentobject.title);`
`

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you implement `setOnClickListener` inside `Adapter` of `RecyclerView`. You can refer to my following sample code, then apply its logic to your code. Hope it helps!

```
public class MyRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRVAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    List<String> mStringList;

    public MyRVAdapter(Context mContext, List<String> mStringList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mStringList = mStringList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView textView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("key1", textView1.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("key2", textView2.getText().toString());

                passToAnotherActivity(bundle);
            }
        });
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // do something...
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mStringList != null) {
            return mStringList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private void passToAnotherActivity(Bundle bundle) {
        if (mContext == null)
            return;
        if (mContext instanceof MainActivity) {
            MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) mContext;
            activity.passToAnotherActivity(bundle); // this method must be implemented inside `MainActivity`
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // do something...
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all make your "itemsdata" object to implement Parcelable. You can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-be-parcelable) . In your onItemClick method you pass the object to your Details activity using intent.putExtra("key",listOfDataItems.get(position)); 
In your DetailsActivity you can get your custom object with getParcelable("key")

Answer (score 1):

All above methods worked, but kinda long, so this one worked for me :

```
Cardview cardview;
            cardView = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);

        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent (view.getContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("TitleKey",ProbTitle.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("DescrKey",ProbDescr.getText().toString());
                view.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

And in Details.java :

```
    TextView title;
TextView Descr;
        title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.details_title);
    Descr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.details_descr);

    String titleresult = result.getExtras().getString("TitleKey");
    String Descrresult = result.getExtras().getString("DescrKey");

    title.setText(titleresult);
    Descr.setText(Descrresult);
```

Comment: if anyone didn't understand, my problem was in passing the clicked item title, so this worked for me, thanks a lot for your answers .

Comment: what is "result" above that you use with getExtras().getString()?

Comment: Is it used with "Intent result = getIntent()"?

Comment: Yes, its used with getIntent();